# Algebraic notation of floor function in an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have the following equation as a question for homework: $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = 2\lfloor x\rfloor$

I know what the solution is by deducting to the possibilities.
Meaning this equation is true for any x which is between n (an integer) and $n+y$ where $0\leq y < \frac{1}{2}$

putting it simple:
\begin{align}
x \in \lbrace n + y | n \in \mathbb{Z} , y \in [0, 0.5) \rbrace
\end{align}
I just don't know how to algebraically get to this solution.
Help will be appreciated!

Comment: $y$ is an unnecessary complication (though not wrong), so you could have "... this equation is true for any $x$ which is from $n$ (an integer) up to but not including $n+\frac{1}{2}$ i.e.  $x \in \left[n,n+\frac{1}{2}\right), \; n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to replace manipulation of the floor function with manipulation of the fractional part function:
$$\{x\} = x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

Then you have $\lfloor 2x\rfloor = 2\lfloor x \rfloor$ if and only if $2x- \{2x\}  = 2(x - \{x\})$, which holds if and only if $2\{x\} = \{2x\}$, which holds if and only if $0\leq 2\{x\}\lt 1$, which holds if and only if $0\leq \{x\}\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Would that do?

Comment: That definately works, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Note that this proof essentially reduces the equation $\rm\ (mod\ 1)\ $ i.e. it proceeds by analyzing its image  in the "circle group" $\rm\ \mathbb R/\mathbb Z\ =\ \mathbb R\ (mod\ \mathbb Z)\:.$